# puppeteer: chrome is being controlled by automated test software

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I am not abel to disable the info bar using below arguments. Please help me fix this in puppeteer. Thanks

```
const getPage = async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,

    args: ['--start-maximized', 'disable-gpu', '--disable-infobars', '--disable-extensions', '--ignore-certificate-errors'],

  }); // default is true

  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  return page;
};
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you cannot actually remove that pop-up via a bot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer Chrome is being controlled by automated test software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64138152/puppeteer-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software) (even if the question is different, but the required flag is covered in the answer)

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the [`enable-automation` default launch arg](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/master/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md#test--debugging-flags) as well:

```js
const options = {
  args: ['--start-maximized', 'disable-gpu', '--disable-infobars', '--disable-extensions', '--ignore-certificate-errors'],
  headless: false,
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
  defaultViewport: null,
};
browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
```

Comment: This helps but it prompts for save password dialog. Is there a way to disable?

Comment: `'--disable-infobars'` should address this, as you've already used it, I have no idea why it pops up.

Comment: actually removing `--enable-automation` brings it back: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/issues/32 it means you cannot do both at the same time with command-line switches