# "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software." showing up even though bot check passing in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm new to NodeJS and all of its libraries.

I used to make bots and scrappers in Python using Selenium and I remember that Chrome explicitly showed a label telling me that

> "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software."

So I started using UndetectedChromeDriver and that label disappeared because making my programs more "human".

So now I'm using **puppeteer, puppeteer-extra and puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth**.

I followed the instructions on how to use puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth and the program ran good but it showed me the same label as when I used Selenium without the UndetectedChromeDriver and also this label:

> "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software."

> "Chrome for Testing v119.0.6045.105 is only for automated testing. For regular browsing, use a standard version of chrome that updates automatically."

But when loading **https://bot.sannysoft.com/** it has all green boxes which basically means that "I" don't look like a bot.

Here is basic code that triggers the 2 previously shown labels in Chrome:

```
// puppeteer-extra is a drop-in replacement for puppeteer,
// it augments the installed puppeteer with plugin functionality
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });

// add stealth plugin and use defaults (all evasion techniques)
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

(async () => {
  // Launch the browser and open a new blank page
  // Configuration when using StealthPlugin 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless : false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
    
  await page.goto("https://bot.sannysoft.com/");
  finish = prompt("Shall we finish the program?");
  console.log(`Finishing program: ${finish}`);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

As far as I know, when you download puppeteer, it automatically downloads the latest webdriver, and I have double checked that I have the latest **puppeteer, puppeteer-extra and puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth.** versions in my project, so I think the webdriver version shouldn't be a problem.

If chrome can tell I'm a bot then other pages can, right?

But if https://bot.sannysoft.com/ tells me that I don't look like a bot and also puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth is in theory making me not to look like a bot then why does chrome tells me that I am a bot?

Should I ignore chrome labels or is puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth not working any longer?

Are there any fixes?

Comment: The message means the remote debugging/developer service is attached. Not sure how UndetectedChromeDriver manages to work without that.

Comment: So i should trust  the plugin?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. That message is for the benefit of users on that computer. By itself, it's not detectable from a web site. Some sites are more aggressive at checking for bots than others. It's only a problem for you if the site is preventing access because it doesn't like what you're doing. If you get the results you want, then don't worry about if your app is detectable or not.

Comment: Ok mate, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

This makes the label disappear

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless : false,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
  });
```

source:
[Puppeteer Chrome is being controlled by automated test software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64138152/puppeteer-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software?rq=2)

Comment: This is helpful, but I don't think it answers the question. I think OP is asking why this banner shows up in the first place. OP wants to make the warning disappear by means of proper robot bypassing practices, not by force-suppressing it. They're worried that because the message shows up, it implies that the stealth plugin isn't really doing its job as well as a similar Selenium plugin they've used in the past.